Can we catch signals from a cellphone using an external device?
What if someone stole em waves from our mobile devices to listen to our conversations or get our OTP. Whatever encryptions they have they are just EM waves innit and they cannot be propagated only in one direction. They have a range in which we can access this wave. Based on the patterns of these waves one can train an ai to decode these waves to information. Is it possible to make a fake receiver and receive all the data from some one else's cell phone?
I don't have even the basics of antenna technology. Here's what I think would be possible.

Create a receiver antennae using primitive technology.
Tune it to match cellphone frequency.
Analyse the waves and search for patterns.
Feed it to a Neural Network (We can train using our own data.)
Decode the informations.

Is it possible to do So?
If the decryption is not possible is it possible to at least make a signal jammer using destructive interference?

Before mobile phone protocols became encrypted, a roommate and I could listen on nearby calls with a scanner he bought in Asia.  That was ca. 1991 though.  Do the current phone-to-tower protocols have encryption that's easy to break?  I don't know.

The first two? Yes.
The third one? Yes, you can search for patterns, and you'll find them, because not all the information is encrypted. The encrypted information probably won't have patterns, or if it does, those patterns wont be helpful for decryption.
4? Yes, you can feed anything into a neural network.
5? No, because neural networks aren't magic. You can try this out with way fewer steps, by just generating your own plaintext, encrypting it with something (like AES), and then using that to train a neural network. You'll see that you never get any useful output.
You'll find more detailed explanations like this and this - the core reason is that "Neural Networks can approximate continuous functions, meaning that a small change in the input values causes a small change in the output value, while encryption functions/algorithm are designed to be as non-continuous as possible."
Yes, you can jam cellphones, and no, you don't need a neural network for that. You can buy cellphone jammers off the shelf, but it is very illegal to use them unless you're the government.
